# JQuery Accordion Menu Compatible with ThemeRoller

Tags: jquery, menu, accordion, themeroller

I'm trying to create left navigation menu with JQuery's accordion. I want it to have look-n-feel from themeroller. 
Unfortunately, i can't find a complete example. There are examples of jquery accordions, there are examples of left navigation menus, there are example of themeroller skinning, but i can't find a simple "copy-paste" example.

I would greatly appreciate if someone could point in direction of "themeroller compatible left navigation accordion menu":)

Thanks,
Philopator.